# Time series statistical model evaluation: weighted average across different forecast horizons

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, arima, model-evaluation

I want to use an ARIMA based or Prophet-based model to train on my data. I have split my data into train and test, and the model is trained on train only and forecasts for test.

The further the forecasts in the test, the worse the error, since it has been trained on train and further down the line from the train, the model might err more. In that case when evaluating the test data forecasts for the error metrics, shouldn't we take a weighted average considering the proximity of the forecasts to the end of train data as the weight since they would be more accurate?

Would love your thoughts on this, thanks for the help in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That depends on what exactly you want to evaluate. If you want to evaluate how well the model predicts $h$ steps ahead, instead of a single split into training and test you could use rolling or expanding windows (see e.g. [section 5.10](https://otexts.com/fpp3/tscv.html) of Hyndman & Athanasopoulos "Forecasting: Principles and Practice"). You would apply a loss function on the prediction errors (or more generally, the predictions and the actual values) and would obtain the distribution of losses over the test cases. You could then take some summary metric of the loss distribution such as mean loss.

If you want to evaluate how well the model predicts for several different horizons $h$, you could do the same for each horizon and then construct a weighted average of mean losses (or some other combination) depending on how important the accuracy of the predictions for each horizon is. E.g. if one step ahead is twice as important as two steps ahead, you could either reflect it in the loss function (double the loss for one step ahead relative to two steps ahead) or by weighting the mean losses of the different horizons accordingly (double weight vs. unit weight).

Comment: But in both the above suggested scenarios, the time complexity is quite high since we have to retrain the model multiple times, I want to use normal train and test split and then predict for test and compare to actual test values. In that case, should I apply weighted average for the further out the prediction values are?

Comment: @albin02t, you can use rolling windows without reestimating the model parameters in each window. Estimate the parameters once, then roll the model by only updating the data according to the window. Regarding the weights in the weighted average, this depends on which forecasts (how many steps ahead) are the most important to you, as I describe in the second paragraph of my answer. This is not a statistical question in a theoretical sense, this is really about what the user finds important.

Comment: Even in the case without reestimating the parameters, the residuals and the coefficients of the model equation would be computed differently depending on the training set and it would take time for each training. So for eg. I want the forecast for the next 20 days and my test split is also 20 days, and I use a normal train-test split, should I apply weighted average?

Comment: @albin02t, no, the coefficients of the model would not change, so it would not take much time at all. (If they change, you are doing something wrong.) Also, why throw away 19 observations by looking only the first one for measuring one step ahead forecast accuracy? That would be madness from the perspective of efficient use of data. Regarding weighted average, I refer back to the second paragraph of my answer.

Comment: But isn't the coefficients of the lagged variables in the model set as per the training set for eg. in arima? For the eg. I want the multi-step accuracy for 20 steps, should i apply wighted average in that case?

Comment: @albin02t, if you want to save time and not reestimate the model's parameters (coefficients) in each window, then you estimate them once (in the first window). Together with data, the model's parameters produce a forecast. You compare the forecast with the actual realization. Then you roll the window but keep the parameters intact; you only update the data values. That produces another forecast. You repeat this until you run out of data. Regarding weighted average, I refer you back to the second paragraph of my answer (which I have expanded for greater clarity).

Comment: Okay thanks got it, also just had one more question. If i am concerned with the forecast for a horizon h, and when applying the rolling window, should i go forward by h steps when retraining the model or just by 1 step. In rob hyndman, they go forward by only 1 step but in that case won't the model take a long time ?

Comment: @albin02t, there is a trade-off between how much data you use and how long the calculations take. You can roll the window by 1 observations each time for maximum use of data or by more observations for faster calculation. For the fastest calculation, do not reestimate the model at all, just roll it as I have explained in previous comment. Note that just rolling is very fast, so if you are not reestimating, then definitely roll by only 1 observations each time.

Comment: Thanks for that, really helps. But just wanted to know what is the correct practice, re-estimating the model or rolling the values for the model in cross validation. Ideally, it should be the same model but trained again with more data since we are cross-validatin a single model right  and not multiple versions of it?

Comment: @albin02t, yes, reestimating is the way to go. That is what I suggested right at the start. Your take makes sense.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that helps been trying to understand timeseries cross validation for sometime!